Why React useState setter does not reflect within a function?
I am trying to get the data from React useState in a function, where the data is also SET in the same function. I need it to be this way because I need to get the data from useState to make validation before call an API.
Every submit button press will call the function onSubmit. However the issue is that on first press it will always tell that the form is Valid, even there is an error. It only went correct on the second press of the button.
Below is the code example :
const [bookingToDateError, setBookingToDateError] = useState<string | undefined>();
const [bookingFromDateError, setBookingFromDateError] = useState<string | undefined>();


const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormFields> = async (data) => {
   await validating(data);
   await submitBooking();
};


const validating = async (data: FormFields) => {
    const timeNow = new Date();
    const bookingFromDate = new Date(data.bookingfromdate);
    const bookingToDate = new Date(data.bookingtodate);

    if (dateIsBefore(bookingFromDate, timeNow) === true) {
      setBookingFromDateError("Date and time cannot before current datetime");
    } else {
      setBookingFromDateError(undefined);
    }

    if (dateIsBefore(bookingToDate, timeNow) === true) {
      setBookingToDateError("Date and time cannot before current datetime");
    } else {
      setBookingToDateError(undefined);
    }
};



const submitBooking = async () => {
    if (
      bookingFromDateError === undefined &&
      bookingToDateError === undefined
    ) {
      console.log("Form is valid, can proceed");
      // I can call api here
    } else {
      console.log("Form is not valid, cannot proceed");
      // show error message cuz form is not valid
    }
};


Please kindly help to provide a more complete code example for your issue. Like how you render things, if it's a children or parent component, where is the onSubmit function getting executed, etc.

That's because you'll have the updated states only after a new render.
Anyway, break apart the orignal code:
const validateFrom = (data: FormFields) => {
    const timeNow = new Date();
    const bookingFromDate = new Date(data.bookingfromdate);

    if (dateIsBefore(bookingFromDate, timeNow) === true) {
      return "Date and time cannot before current datetime";
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
};

Same job for the "to date", so that you'll have a validateTo function.
At this point, move the logic in the onSubmit function:
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormFields> = async (data) => {
   const fromDateError = validateFrom(data);
   const toDateError = validateTo(data);
   setBookingFromDateError(fromDateError);
   setBookingToDateError(toDateError);

   if (
      fromDateError === undefined &&
      toDateError === undefined
    ) {
      console.log("Form is valid, can proceed");
      // I can call api here
    } else {
      console.log("Form is not valid, cannot proceed");
      // show error message cuz form is not valid
    }
};

That's it.
Another approach is to validate upon any date change, and the error message will appear as soon a selection is invalid. That condition should also disable the submit button.
All that is just a cosmetic protection, and you should always protect your backend from invalid inputs, by rejecting the submission.
